# Column is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am getting an error on a `SELECT` query when I am trying to use `ORDER BY` clause. When I remove `ORDER BY` it works fine.

Here is my query:

```
Select  tbl_User.CompanyName as CompanyName,
    tbl_User.ResellerName as ResellerName,
    tbl_New_Web_Amc.Domain_Name,
    tbl_Website_Type.Website_type as [Type],
    convert(varchar,Web_Amc_Start_Date,106) as StartDate,
    convert(varchar,Web_Amc_End_Date,106) as EndDate,
    tbl_New_Web_Amc.Web_Amc_Amount as Amount,
    tbl_Billing.CompanyName as BillingCompany,
    tbl_Billing.ContactPerson1,
    tbl_Billing.Mobile1,
    tbl_Billing.ContactPerson2,
    tbl_Billing.Mobile2,
    tbl_Billing.ContactPerson3,
    tbl_Billing.Mobile3,
    tbl_Billing.Telephone1,
    tbl_Billing.Telephone2,
    tbl_Billing.Telephone3,
    tbl_Billing.EmailId1,
    tbl_Billing.EmailId2,
    tbl_Billing.EmailId3
from tbl_New_Web_Amc 
   join tbl_User on tbl_New_Web_Amc.Customer_Id=tbl_User.UserId 
   join tbl_Domain_Details on tbl_New_Web_Amc.Customer_Id=tbl_Domain_Details.Customer_Id
   join tbl_Billing on tbl_New_Web_Amc.Customer_Id=tbl_Billing.User_ID
   join tbl_Website_Type on tbl_Website_Type.Type_Id=tbl_New_Web_Amc.Web_Amc_Site_Type
   where WebsiteAmc_Id is not null
group by tbl_User.CompanyName ,
    tbl_User.ResellerName ,
    tbl_New_Web_Amc.Domain_Name,
    tbl_Website_Type.Website_type,
    convert(varchar,Web_Amc_End_Date,106),
    convert(varchar,Web_Amc_Start_Date,106),
    tbl_New_Web_Amc.Web_Amc_Amount,
    tbl_Billing.CompanyName,
    tbl_Billing.ContactPerson1,
    tbl_Billing.ContactPerson2,
    tbl_Billing.ContactPerson3,
    tbl_Billing.Telephone1,
    tbl_Billing.Telephone2,
    tbl_Billing.Telephone3,
    tbl_Billing.Mobile1,
    tbl_Billing.Mobile2,
    tbl_Billing.Mobile3,
    tbl_Billing.EmailId1,
    tbl_Billing.EmailId2,
    tbl_Billing.EmailId3
    order by convert(datetime,Web_Amc_End_Date,106)
```

Getting the following Error

> Column "tbl_New_Web_Amc.Web_Amc_End_Date" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Where I am going wrong. How to rectify it?? Please help.

Comment: @marc_s I have taken every column in Group By clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ORDER BY command requires the exact column to be present in the select query as well, since as per the order in SQL Server the order by command is executed after the SELECT command. From what I can gather in your query, you have used:

```
convert(varchar,Web_Amc_End_Date,106)
```

in the select clause, and

```
convert(datetime,Web_Amc_End_Date,106)
```

in the order by clause.

Consider changing them to the same format, your query will work

Comment: "When GROUP BY (and UNION and SELECT DISTINCT) ORDER BY command requires the exact column to be present..."

Comment: @Navy, ohh ok :D
Refresh latency is to blame :D

Answer (score 0):

You already have that expression in the SELECT statement and use the alias in the ORDER BY clause

```
Select  tbl_User.CompanyName as CompanyName,
    tbl_User.ResellerName as ResellerName,
    tbl_New_Web_Amc.Domain_Name,
    tbl_Website_Type.Website_type as [Type],
    convert(varchar,Web_Amc_Start_Date,106) as StartDate,
    convert(varchar,Web_Amc_End_Date,106) as EndDate,
    tbl_New_Web_Amc.Web_Amc_Amount as Amount,
    tbl_Billing.CompanyName as BillingCompany,
    tbl_Billing.ContactPerson1,
    tbl_Billing.Mobile1,
    tbl_Billing.ContactPerson2,
    tbl_Billing.Mobile2,
    tbl_Billing.ContactPerson3,
    tbl_Billing.Mobile3,
    tbl_Billing.Telephone1,
    tbl_Billing.Telephone2,
    tbl_Billing.Telephone3,
    tbl_Billing.EmailId1,
    tbl_Billing.EmailId2,
    tbl_Billing.EmailId3
from tbl_New_Web_Amc 
   join tbl_User on tbl_New_Web_Amc.Customer_Id=tbl_User.UserId 
   join tbl_Domain_Details on tbl_New_Web_Amc.Customer_Id=tbl_Domain_Details.Customer_Id
   join tbl_Billing on tbl_New_Web_Amc.Customer_Id=tbl_Billing.User_ID
   join tbl_Website_Type on tbl_Website_Type.Type_Id=tbl_New_Web_Amc.Web_Amc_Site_Type
   where WebsiteAmc_Id is not null
group by tbl_User.CompanyName ,
    tbl_User.ResellerName ,
    tbl_New_Web_Amc.Domain_Name,
    tbl_Website_Type.Website_type,
    convert(varchar,Web_Amc_End_Date,106),
    convert(varchar,Web_Amc_Start_Date,106),
    tbl_New_Web_Amc.Web_Amc_Amount,
    tbl_Billing.CompanyName,
    tbl_Billing.ContactPerson1,
    tbl_Billing.ContactPerson2,
    tbl_Billing.ContactPerson3,
    tbl_Billing.Telephone1,
    tbl_Billing.Telephone2,
    tbl_Billing.Telephone3,
    tbl_Billing.Mobile1,
    tbl_Billing.Mobile2,
    tbl_Billing.Mobile3,
    tbl_Billing.EmailId1,
    tbl_Billing.EmailId2,
    tbl_Billing.EmailId3
    order by EndDate
```

Comment: But i need to convert EndDate in particular format. So that it display result in proper order.